# woocommerce how to change <p> tag class on Register Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

i want to change in my eshop the text of

class in Register Page.

Text : "A link to set a new password will be sent to your email address"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGRcq.png)

Answer (score 0):

try to look at woocomerce settings, or change it manualy at code, you can find code fragment by file search, in PhpStorm it`s like a ctrl+shift+f

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).